# Controller to directive data sharing after webservice request

Tags: angularjs

My directive scope.file is coming up undefined, it comes ok if i assign $scope.file before rest call. here is my code

```
<radioplayer file="file"></radioplayer>
angular.module('radioModule').
    controller('stateController', function ($scope,$stateParams,$http) {
        console.log($stateParams.name);
        var url=window.location.href;
        $scope.name=$stateParams.name;
        $scope.artist=$stateParams.ct;
        $scope.globalLoading = true;
        $http.get(url+'getstationCur.php', {params: {id: $stateParams.id}}).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data.split('\n')[2]);
            $scope.file="my audio file";
            $scope.globalLoading = false;

        });


 });
```

and directive code

```
angular.module('radioModule').
    directive('radioplayer', function () {
        function link(scope, element, attrs){
         element.html(scope.file);
           console.log(scope.file);
        }
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{
              file:'=file'
            },
            link:link
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive is running before the $scope.file variable is set by the controller, hence undefined being logged.

You can use a $watch within the directive to register a function to be run when $scope.file changes.

```
.directive('radioplayer', function ($log) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch('file', function(newVal, oldVal){
            element.html(scope.file);  
            $log.log(scope.file);
        });
    }
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
          file:'=file'
        },
        link:link
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$watch is a little expensive operation.
For your case, simple trick I think, would be to define var parent=this; as variable in controller and assigning file in rest call as below:
parent.file="my audio file";

The rest call takes a different scope than parent. Going by above may help.